# delete or free on object causes Arduino to hand or reboot

Tags: c++, memory-usage, memory

I've read a lot about dynamic allocation for strings or buffers, but that's not my case.

I plan to implement much blinkers types as classes, all inheriting from a base `Action` class.

I declare an array of 10 pointers because I want to limit to 10 blinkers simultaneously at most :

```
Action** actions = new Action*[10];
```

In the code, I will do something like :

```
int i = GetFreeActionID();
actions[i] = new ActionLightBlinkerMono(myPin, onDuration, offDuration);
```

Then the loop will call a method of the object and it works fine.

When it comes to stop the blinking, I would just destroy the object and set the pointer to zero, so the loop will not try to call the method of the object anymore :

```
if (actions[i]->Do() != 0)
{
  delete(actions[i]);
  actions[i] == 0;
}
```

Howerver, I see in the serial console that when it comes to the `delete` instruction, the Arduino just reboots itself ...

Tryed also `free` instead of `delete` with same result.

How could I safely free the object when it's not used anymore ?

It's an evidence I don't know what will be used at compile time, the blinkers will be started by the user (via I2C instructions) at runtime, hence instanciating different classes.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). `Action** actions = new Action*[10];` - you aren't declaring an array of 10 pointers, you are declaring an array of 10 pointers to pointers. Is this really what you want?

Comment: *It's an evidence I don't know what will be used at compile time, the blinkers will be started by the user (via I2C instructions) at runtime, hence instanciating different classes.* - I don't understand that at all.

Comment: i'd really like to understand, I felt I was declaring a pointer to an array of pointers, not an array of pointers to pointers, I thought an array of pointers to pointers would have been something like `Action** actions[10];`

Comment: Ah yes, you are probably right there. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>   actions[i] == 0;
> ```

That statement has no useful effect. Perhaps you mean:

```
actions[i] = 0;
```

Comment: oh god, man, you saved my life! Sometimes I feel my eyes need glasses ... Such a mistake, it works perfectly now!